# Why is SVG textPath not working in Firefox when rendered by React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, svg

I'm trying to render a react component with an inline SVG element that has a text along a path. This is what is returned from the render method:

```
        <div className="textsvg">
            <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-50 -50 100 100">
                <defs>
                    <path id="textPathTop" d={`
                            M 0 40
                            A 40,40 0 0 1 0,-40
                            A 40,40 0 0 1 0,40`}></path>
                    <path id="textPathBottom" d={`
                            M 0 -41.8
                            A 41.8,41.8 0 0 0 0,41.8
                            A 41.8,41.8 0 0 0 0,-41.8`}></path>
                </defs>
                <use xlinkHref="#textPathBottom" fill="none" stroke="red"></use>
                <text fill="red" fontSize="4.5"><textPath xlinkHref="#textPathBottom">We go up, then we go down, then up again</textPath></text>
                </svg>
        </div>
```

This shows the "We go up, then we go down, then up again" text, but just in a straight horizontal line starting from 0,0.

Copying the resulting html into a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dWOYRO) shows the result as it should look, using the textPath.
Why is the textPath ignored when rendered with ReactJS?

Using React 15.3.1 and checking in FF 52.0.2(32bit)

Already tried using _dangerouslySetInnerHTML for textPath, but that didn't work either.

Comment: is the red stroked path displayed ?

Comment: no, the red path isn't displayed too, so it looks like somehow the defs aren't processed or found.

Comment: I would rather suspect a bug with xlink namespace.

Comment: so how could I check, debug or fix that?

Comment: still stuck here...

Comment: [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ft2awmLL/) forked from the one from [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2250#issuecomment-229471922) does work for me. Read [the issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2250) for more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if you have a <base href="..."> tag in your <head> element.

If so, Firefox won't be able to display your text, while Chrome will.

Firefox is searching for your xlink:href attribute at the base href url, it does not find it, so the text is just ignored.

A workaround is to use an absolute url :

```
<textPath xlink:href="http://pathtoyourpage#textPathBottom">
```

It is easier if you generate the svg with javascript :

```
textPath.setAttribute('xlink:href', `${location.href}#textPathBottom`)
```

Some similar weird behavior happen with mask and filter attributes.